# Best way to non-dimensionalise equation of vertical motion with damping and external Force

Tags: mathematical-physics, mathematical-modeling, classical-mechanics, dimensional-analysis

Trying to non-dimensionalise the following equation and wondering what the best way would be?

Any ideas would be appreciated.

Thanks[image: Eqution of vertical motion with Damping and external force]

Comment: Do you know about the Buckingham Pi Theorem?

Comment: No, not aware of it, what is it?